# group_by mutate not working in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm pretty confident this is "operator error", but would appreciate any help. 
I have an (example) data frame

```
foo <- data.frame("School"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 "Grade"=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                  "e2005" = c(180,221,193,192,218,209,211,236,222,283,195,225),
                  "e2006" = c(207,194,234,204,208,228,224,216,235,265,263,191))
```

and am trying to calculate ratios using mutate and lag in dplyr. I want to group_by "School", and as 4 is the last grade in any school, the resulting new variable "r2006" (for every school) should be NA. But I have done something (maybe much) wrong. After struggling with this for hours, I would much appreciate any assistance that is offered.

Code that I am running:

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>%
group_by(School)
mutate(foo,    r2006 = (foo[, 4] / lag(foo[, 3])))
```

The desired result is:

```
School  Grade   2005    2006    r2006
1       1       180     207     NA
1       2       221     194     1.077777778
1       3       193     234     1.058823529
1       4       192     204     1.056994819
2       1       218     208     NA
2       2       209     228     1.04587156
2       3       211     224     1.071770335
2       4       236     216     1.023696682
3       1       222     235     NA
3       2       283     265     1.193693694
3       3       195     263     0.929328622
3       4       225     191     0.979487179
```

But what I am getting is:

```
School  Grade   2005    2006    r2006
1       1       180     207     NA
1       2       221     194     1.077777778
1       3       193     234     1.058823529
1       4       192     204     1.056994819
2       1       218     208     1.083333333
2       2       209     228     1.04587156
2       3       211     224     1.071770335
2       4       236     216     1.023696682
3       1       222     235     0.995762712
3       2       283     265     1.193693694
3       3       195     263     0.929328622
3       4       225     191     0.979487179
```

I suspect that I am either not handling the lag function properly, or I've done something else wrong.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Patrick

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0         RevoUtilsMath_8.0.3
```

Comment: A few things. First, you are missing `%>%` in the line of group_by. Second, you do not have to call `foo` in mutate. Third, you can use column names to do your work in mutate. Your code would be: `foo %>%  group_by(School) %>% mutate(r2006 = (e2006 / lag(e2005)))`

Comment: `mutate(foo, r2006 = (e2006/lag(e2005)))`. Or you can chain the whole thing: `foo %>%
  group_by(School) %>%
  mutate(r2006 = (e2006/lag(e2005)))`. Either way, you should refer to variables by their unquoted names. By using `foo[,3]` and `foo[,4]` you've reached out into the global environment's copy of `foo` rather than using the `foo` you inserted into `mutate` with the data argument.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you (both) very much. Both of these solutions work for me and thank you for pointing out my errors to me. Cheers, Patrick